# Condense list into string : ['z','y','x'...] -> 'zyx...' ? Python (2.7.1)

Tags: python, string, list, translate, letters

If I have 
list='abcdedcba'

and i want:
a=z, b=y, c=x, d=w, e=v
so it would translate to:

translate='zyxwvwxya'

How would I do this?
If I construct a dictionary

```
>>> d=dict(zip(('a','b','c','d','e'),('z','y','x','w','v')))
```

and type

```
>>> example= d[x] for x in list
>>> print translate
['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

How do I get it back into the form

translate='zyxwvwxyz'

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
the_list = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
print "".join(the_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

For monoalphabetic substitution, use [maketrans](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [translate](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate) from the string module. They operate like the unix [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) command. Joining with an empty separator is the correct answer for that last step, but not necessary for this exact task.

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join(translate)
```

I'm not sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

an example of using maketrans and translate:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('abcdef', 'zyxwvu')
>>> 'abdedddfdffdabe'.translate(table)
'zywvwwwuwuuwzyv'
```

Assuming you want to substitute all letters in the ASCII alphabet:

```
import string
reversed_ascii_letters = string.ascii_letters[::-1]
# reorder lowercase and uppercase
reversed_ascii_letters = reversed_ascii_letters[26:] + reversed_ascii_letters[:26]
table = string.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, reversed_ascii_letters)
data = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over the Lazy Dog'
print data.translate(table)
```

Comment: `'abdedddfdffdabe'` has the `translate()` method, so you can just use `'abdedddfdffdabe'.translate(table)`

Comment: so with this i could just skip the dictionary step?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans(string.lowercase, string.lowercase[::-1])
>>> 'abcdedcba'.translate(table)
'zyxwvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.lowercase
>>> letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> def revert_string(s):
    s_rev = ''
    for c in s:
        s_rev += letters[len(letters) - 1 - letters.find(c)]
    return s_rev

>>> s = 'zearoizuetlkzjetkl'
>>> revert_string(s)
'avzilrafvgopaqvgpo'
```